# 1C 8.3. Как установить функцию, чтобы срабатывало при открытии любого документа?

Tags: 1с

Как в 1C 8.3 установить функцию, чтобы срабатывало при открытии любого документа? (насколько я понял, нужно в общих модулях это сделать)

Answer (score 0):

В 1С предусмотрен механизм "*Подписки на события*", когда указанная программистом процедура вызывается при возникновении определенного события. Найти подписки можно в конфигурации *Общие - Подписки на события* ; Чтобы посмотреть какие события обрабатываются, создай новую подписку, затем заполни в свойствах: *Источник, Событие, Обработчик*

Однако событие открытия Документа - не предусмотрено ! Если необходимо выполнить свой код *в момент открытия **Формы Документа***, - необходимо разместить его *в модуле **Формы Документа***, при этом в свойствах Формы в самом низу, есть список Событий;